# assigning a value to a String variable in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

Is the any way to assign a value from the text field to a jsp/java String variable with out submitting the form ?

i.,e

i need to assign <%String s="";%>//that means it must hold xyz value with out submitting the button.

Comment: Nope...but you can do clever ajax if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Without submitting the form? Well, not possible. The text field value is on the client side while the JSP scriptlet is on the server side. In order for you to set a value in the JSP scriptlet using the text field value, you will need to submit the form.